# Error "argument type f "int" is incompatable with parameter of type "int*" and 'int assignVal(int[])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int[]'

Tags: c++, arrays, arguments

For a class assignment I have to fill multiple array types with random numbers. Here is the code I have but keep getting the above error message:

```
Error "argument type f "int" is incompatable with parameter of type "int*" 
 and 'int assignVal(int[])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int[]'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, here the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int len = 5;

int assignVal(int array[len]);

int main()
{
    double arr1[len];
    int arr2[len];
    int arr3[len];

    assignVal(arr2[len]);

}
int assignVal(int array[len])
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) 
    {
        array[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your call:

```
assignVal(arr2[len]);
```

THis does not do what you think:  it calls the function with the len-th element of arr2 array.  So you try to pass an int element instead of the array.

Try:

```
assignVal(arr2);
```